# Windows Error reporting stopped one service?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, service, windows-service

I have the problem with one service in win2k8

One of my service terminated unexpectedly while going through event logs i have following logs

```
Event 7036  Source - service control manager
The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the running state.
```

After this log , it shows our application service was terminated unexpectedly

```
 Event 7034 Source - service control manager
    LK  service  terminated unexpectedly. It has done this time(s).
```

Next, the Windows Error reporting entered stopped state

```
 Event 7036 Source - service control manager
    The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the Stopped state.
```

what made the service terminate unexpectedly, in any case WER cause the service to terminate?

Comment: In this scenario to understand why the process is crashing, I would install Procdump (Microsoft/Sysinternals) as the post-mortem debugger - 
 `procdump -i -ma C:\dumps`.  Next time the problem occurs, you need to an analyze the dump file created in `C:\dumps\` with Windbg for example.  Windbg can be obtained installing the SDK and checking the Debugging Tools for Windows.

Comment: so, we need to install procdump and  windbg for the purpose

Comment: You don't need to install Windbg on the server.  Once Procdump has been "installed" (just creates reg keys to point to itself) and you have obtained the dump(s) you can move the dump files to any computer with Windbg on for analysis.  You only need to "install" Procdump until you have created the dump(s).  You can uninstall it (removed the registry keys it created) by running `procdump -u`.

Comment: i assume it creates a dump file using procdump ,  i run the above command but dumps files were not created

Comment: With Procdump “installed”. Next time a process crashes a dump will be written to c:\dumps\

Comment: I used process explorer to test  dumps, but even after killing a process its not making any dump file. anything missing here ?

Comment: Killing a process in that way is not likely to trigger an exception in a the target process such that it will create a dump file.  The original post suggests you had a process which presumably was the "LK  service" that crashed and you asked why did it crash.  With procdump "installed/registered", if it happens again, when it crashes in the future you should have a full dump in C:\dumps\.  If you can't reproduce the crash in the service you might just have to wait until next time if that even happens at all.  At least with Procdump installed you should get a dump to work with next time.

Comment: informative and i will  keep this running untill  the next crash

Comment: @HelpingHand , I got one more question and will  like to see your feedback  .. (https://serverfault.com/questions/917433/how-does-windows-service-control-manager-works)

Answer (score 2):

> what made the service terminate unexpectedly

That would be hard to answer without any details - except that is has crashed. Does your application write any logfiles? Are there hints in other eventlogs?

> in any case WER cause the service to terminate?

[WER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513613(v=vs.85).aspx) starts when a service *has been* terminated, it is not able to terminate your processes.

Windows Error Reporting is a event-based feedback infrastructure designed to gather information about the problems that Windows can detect, report the information to Microsoft, and provide users with available solutions.

Beginning with Windows Vista, Windows provides crash, no response, and kernel fault error reporting by default without requiring changes to your application. Applications instead use the WER API to generate error reports for application-specific issues that are not related to crashes, non-responses, or kernel faults.

To generate error reports for application-specific issues, the application must create a short description of the problem using a few basic pieces of information called report parameters. Report parameters include information such as the application name, application version, module name, module version, and error code. The combination of these report parameters describes a unique problem.

Comment: nothing is registered in our log files, moreover, these services are configured  for fail over  using a third party cluster application and  that application is controlling this services